# Serial Port access in multiple forms: Module Implementation method

Tags: vb.net, module, serial-port

I would like to use the same serial port instance in multiple forms. There is the possibility of a singleton class or the module. I'm new to VB.Net so I don't know how to implement the singleton pattern with events. I understood the basic definition but I couldn't add the events or know how to access them programmatically.

I found also the module solution:

```
Module Module1
Public WithEvents mySerialPort1 As New IO.Ports.SerialPort

Private Sub mySerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, _
                                       e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
                                   Handles mySerialPort1.DataReceived
End Sub
End Module
```

My Questions are:

- Does the name of the serial port instance have to be the same as the serial port control I added to the project?
- Normally to add an event handler, one double clicks on the event and the Sub definition of the event appears. Can I do that also in the module ? If I do it in my project, It automatically appears in the code of the main form. Is it a problem if I just move it to the module?
- How does the use of the module with the serial port instance and its event look in a real programm? (an example?)

Here is a decription of my Application:

Form 1: Start Page
Detect the port where the microcontroller is connected and opens it. The form receives data from the microcontroller through the serial port. This data is then displayed in a Datagrid.

Form 2: The user fills in Data in the datagridview. The data is then sent through the serial port to the microcontroller.

Both forms use the same port.

I would like to declare the serial port in a module and access it and its events from both forms.

Thanks a lot for bearing my quite basic questions!

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to add the control to a form.  You already provided both the instance and the event in your Module.  Your form needs to use it, exactly how you distribute the data that is received by the event is up to you.  Maybe you need a ConcurrentQueue, hard to guess when you don't tell us what these form classes do.  It is just simpler to keep the port usage confined to a single form that is always available.  In general just don't put it on the center stage in your UI, it is just plumbing that the user doesn't care for.  Spend the time to decide what a useful UI looks like.

Comment: Ah you mean if I instantiate it in the Module I don't need to drag the control and place it on the UI?
I defnitely need at least two userforms  to use the same port. I will add the description of the allpication now in the question so you can have a clearer idea. 
Concerning the definition of the eventhandler subroutine: does it make a difference if it is in the main form or in the module ?